# Anybody knows if there is a counterpart for CTR+w , that deletes immediate words after cursor

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh

I mean when the cursor is on the left side of the words ,I would like to remove the words on the immediate right side of it . CTR+k remove everything on the right side, i only want one word to be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Many keyboards will work with `Alt` as `Meta` so you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

In my bash shells, I hit ESC and 'd'.

Answer (score 0):

Bash tends to use libreadline for commandline input, so you can create an inputrc file that lets you control what keystrokes do what.  `man readline 3` should explain the format, you can also find this in the READLINE section of bash's manpage (the specific command you want is `kill-word`)

zsh doesn't use libreadline apparently, but it seems they've mimicked a lot of the functionality.  It looks like [there are some options to mimic bash's word matching](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#SEC283), but you'll need to bind them to a key.